# MongoDB Ubuntu installation taking hours

Tags: performance, mongodb, ubuntu, installation, apt-get

Can anyone direct me to a better way to install MongoDB on Ubuntu 12.04?

I'm currently using apt-get install mongodb-org, and it's downloading incredibly slow.  I'm behind a fast connection, all other downloads are very fast.  Must be the file server.  Can I use a mirror somehow?  It goes for an hour and then fails.  Not having a good day, as this should take a few minutes.

Comment: Have you followed the MongoDB for Ubuntu documentation here? http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/ In other words, are you using the indicated source(s)?

Comment: Yes I was following those instructions exactly.  The download speed was something around 2k/s... I ended up downloading it from http://www.mongodb.org/downloads (took about 30s) and followed the instructions here:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-linux/

Comment: I'm having the same problem, a very slow download speed and since the download via `apt-get` is part of my vagrant bootstrap, this delay impacts the entire `vagrant up` process. A 5 minute process is now taking hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up downloading it from mongodb.org/downloads (took about 30s) and followed the instructions here: docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-linux everything seems to be working fine...